# How many bootstrap links do I need to use at the top of my index.html file to use a template

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use a bootswatch Bootstrap template that you can find here: http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/#bootswatch_tab (The template is Amelia).

Do I only add this to my index.html document:

```
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.1.1/amelia/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

or do I need to add these two as well to make it work:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
```

I figured I just needed the first piece of code but I need it to connect to my style.css document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[For Bootstrap, you need only these by default :](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/)

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Depending on the theme, which you want to use, you will have to go through the source code to check what other external files have been used for layout(`css`) and visible effects(`.js`) for it

go through src and you'll find a url for amelia :

```
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.1.1/amelia/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I don't understand why the theme works without using the CDN HTML Tag they provided by bootswatch (<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.1.1/amelia/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">). We don't have that link href tag anywhere but it still works. Why is this? Also, what do you mean by go through the src? Thanks again!

Comment: when you use CDN, is you PC/Laptop connected to the internet....people tend to make this mistake!|| there must be some way `css` is called, in *mozilla* do *ctrl+u* then *ctrl+f* to find the css file